# Algorithm: Checking for conditions in 3D array

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, list

This one is hard to explain! Sorry for that, but here goes... 
I have a 3D array of some data [X][Y][Z], and I like to check for about 10 different combination conditions and keep only data when it's a match... Example:

```
              X         Y      Z
//myData[1..1000000][1..10][1..10].foo // foo is an int

X[i].Y[ii].Z[iii].foo; // X is a container, Y= 1 to 10 levels. And Z= objects

//I want to apply a "filter" to the Z objects...
```

Lets say I want to find all combinations where the sum of "foo" is smaller and larger than two numbers, and only keep those Z objects

For next iteration i want to find lets say only where "foo" is a prime number, still keeping only Z objects

And so on for more conditions, resulting in smaller and smaller list. 
It doesn't matter in wich order they are performed.
I sort of know how to do it, but I end up in some really nasty loops... 
Any Ideas? Maybe adding to another list is faster than deleting from original list?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes true, I was thinking of it. And passing new array for new conditions, cunstruct new array, check for new conditions, and so on...

Comment: Why not check for all conditions at once? It will get you down to one 3-tier for loop.

Comment: Hm, I think the code will be very hard to maintain / add / change conditions.. but I could give it a try

Comment: Could you please post a C# code sample? What you have there looks like Ruby, and I'm not sure if you have an array of integers or what? I also don't understand "combination conditions" and what you mean by keep Z objects. Are you filtering the list based on the values of foo?

Comment: @Jasmine Trashed the code, didn't work. But it's sort of a "linked"  list with three classes as X[i].Y[ii].Z[iii].foo;

Comment: @Jasmine X is more of container, and Y holds 10 levels, and on each level there can be 1-10 Z objects. Now I want to select all Y-levels wich have Z objects with my "filter" applied to them

Comment: @Half_Baked, Because your conditions are subtractive it shouldn't be too hard to maintain using short-circuiting `&&` operators i.e.(`if(cond1 && cond2 && ... && condN`). No matter what you do, a new condition = more code.

Comment: I will try it. I guess I could add a filed to the Z objects (bool), so instead of deleting them i set them to be not used.. Think it's faster than updating a list

Comment: OK, the solution is in your comment... you want to *select* the Y objects which meet a condition. Use LINQ.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to chain together logic like this, I think you really want to use Linq.  Unfortunately, it can be cumbersome to use Linq on multidimensional arrays.  With some helper methods, though, we can convert the data array into something more usable.  First, let's build a wrapper class for any object that has 3 dimensions associated with it:

```
public class ThreeDimensionalArrayExtension<T> {
     public int X { get; set; }
     public int Y { get; set; }
     public int Z { get; set; }
     public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Next, let's write a helper method that converts 3-dimsensional arrays to IEnumerables of the new type:

```
public static class ThreeDimensionalArrayExtensionMethods {
    public static IEnumerable<ThreeDimensionalArrayExtension<T>> ConvertArray<T>(this T[,,] foos) {
        for(var x = 0; x < foos.GetLength(0); x++) {
            for (var y = 0; y < foos.GetLength(1); y++) {
                for (var z = 0; z < foos.GetLength(2); z++) {
                    yield return new ThreeDimensionalArrayExtension<T> { X = x, Y = y , Z = z, Value = foos[x, y, z] };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that since we are using an iterator block (the yield-return pattern), calling this method does not actually perform any computation.

Now we can use the power of Linq on your 3-dimensional array to filter it however we want!

```
myData.ConvertArray().Where(d => d.Value.Foo > 5)
                     .Where(d => IsPrime(d.Value.Foo))
                     .Where(...);
```

Edit:
I see that you're using 3 nested classes and not a multidimensional array which I assumed you were using.  The goal should still be to convert that object to an IEnumerable upon which you can very easily chain Linq queries to filter or project the data.  In your case, you can do:

```
public static class ThreeDimensionalArrayExtensionMethods {
    public static IEnumerable<ThreeDimensionalArrayExtension<X>> ConvertArray(this X[] foos) {
        for(var x = 0; x < foos.Count(); x++) {
            for (var y = 0; y < foos[x].Count(); y++) {
                for (var z = 0; z < foos[x][y].Count(); z++) {
                    yield return new ThreeDimensionalArrayExtension<T> { X = x, Y = y , Z = z, Value = foos[x][y][z] };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then use the same call to ConvertArray followed by the filtering Where clauses described above.

If you don't care about the X/Y/Z indices, you can also just use `SelectMany` to project the multidimensional list onto a single dimensional list:

```
X.SelectMany(y => y.SelectMany(z => z)).Where(z => z.Foo > 5);
```

Comment: This is assuming you're using a multidimensional array, not a jagged array.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for taking the time to write all that down! Impressive! I will need to study and try linq out.

Comment: Actually using 3 classes, linked together with lists, so it actually X[0].Y[0].Z[0].foo; But same thing I guess....